# Тонкости работы событий в Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  alert('1');
}, true);

document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('2');
}, false);

document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('4');
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Почему события срабатывают в последовательности 1,2,4 а не 1,4.2?
Ведь, согласно документации, события обрабатываются сначала все с параметром true, а затем false.

Comment: а ссылку на эту документацию можно посмотреть?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

Comment: Причем последовательность получается нужной если обработчики у элемента b поменять местами

Comment: Получается еще имеет место быть последовательность регистрации событий

Comment: если на элементе несколько обработчиков, запускается первая зарегистрированная, поправьте если я не прав

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно все той же документации, обработчики этапа *`capture`* вызываются в порядке от родительских элементов к дочерним, а обработчики этапа *`bubble`* - от дочерних к родительским (см. [раздел 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow))

Там же написано, что при достижении элемента, в котором событие возникло непосредственно - этап *`capture`* заканчивается и начинается этап *`target`*.

Таким образом, непосредственные обработчики вызываются вне зависимости от параметра `useCapture`.

Comment: Вопрос был в том, почему на одном элементе, на котором зарегистрированы 2 события, но с разными параметрами, сначала срабатывает событие bubling, а только потом capture - ведь по рисунку видно что первым должно отработать событие capture

Comment: @ruslik понял, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Таким образом, непосредственные обработчики вызываются вне зависимости от параметра useCapture -  то есть в порядке их регистрации, я правильно понял?

Comment: @ruslik да, вы правильно поняли